# Angular Router Navigate re initializes component

Tags: angular, navigation, router

I am navigating from component A to component B using router.navigate with query param. And navigating back from B to A using router.navigate with exact same query param.

1). Is it expected behavior that component A is initialized with new instance when redirected to, from component B?

2). I don't want to reinitialize component A and use that same instance of A. How can I achieve this.

I am using Angular 6

Comment: Yes it is expected, when you navigate from CompA to CompB, do you want the CompA to be visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly prevent components from being destroyed on navigating to a different URL, refer the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy).